# How to get bamboo use different config file on deployment depending on environment

Tags: deployment, continuous-deployment, bamboo, config-transformation

I have different config files for each different deployment environments I have. Dev, QA and live are those environments. 
How do i get bamboo to use the right config file for each environment when deploying?

So when deploying the dev environment bamboo use the dev config file and change name on it and put it on the right place.

I assume that artifacts can fix this? But how?

Comment: Are you using deployment projects or regular Bamboo plans?

Comment: @RichDuncan I dont understand what you mean, but i use this so i assume its bamboo plans? https://gyazo.com/b1ffe3d1ab9bece1099aa1c10c0b576f

Comment: I solved it. I simply used artifacts and pointed directly to the file.
Then in deploy i made a ps script for deploying the right artifact to the right deployment enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. I simply used artifacts and pointed directly to the file. Then in deploy i made a ps script for deploying the right artifact to the right deployment environment. 
I also made the file changing depending on environment so i don't need separately config files.
Just hit me up if you are having the same problem, Atlassian documentation on this is terrible.